# I am making an app with ionic 4.When i try to create buttons from the ts file the buttons do show on the browser But the (onclick) function dont work

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button, ionic4

[Print screen] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWLBX.png

and this is the home.page.html

```
<ion-header > 
 <ion-toolbar >
  <ion-title>HOME</ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
 <div [innerHTML] id="days"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it has all the necessary information required for us to help you. Refer to [ask] for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic 4 has a bunch of changes and the onClick is no longer valid. You should use `<ion-button (click)="myCallback()">`

Comment: Its still doesnt work there is a difference in the html elements with the button that i create through html and the ones i create through typescript.here is the difference -> Prt Sc[Html Difference][https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cBlY.png]

Comment: The one created on the html file gets compiled with the template processor. I’m afraid that you’ll need to create a custom component, add it to the module and reference it in the html. You can use Renderer2 to append the element. (Don’t have a computer here to test)

Comment: Another alternative would be to add the items in a `*ngFor=“let day of days”` loop in the html template bound to the array of days (which can be dynamically generated or fetched from a backend).